# What's the meaning of `support instant apps`? If I check it, what will happen

Tags: android, android-studio

When I create a empty Android Studio Application, in there I have some questions:

[image]

1. What's the meaning of `Failed to load stats. Value maybe out of date`?
2. What's the meaning of `support instant apps`? If I check it, what will happen?
3. What's the meaning of `androidx.* artifacts`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1)It couldn't load more recent stats on usage of various OS versions.  Probably because Google has only been exporting them every few months lately, instead of weekly.  Don't worry about this

2)Its a native app that can be loaded from a website (needs to be small) instead of being installed.  If you don't know what it is, you probably don't need it.

3)Google recently rebranded the Support Library as androidx.  This causes problems when some libraries use the support version of a class and some the androidx version.  This tells the app to try to use the androidx libraries where dependencies want the support libraries.

Comment: I still don't understand the `Its a native app that can be loaded from a website (needs to be small) instead of being installed.`, If load the apk(which user can access by http)  into user's android phone ram?

Comment: Yes.  More or less.  And runs it in a sandbox that allows access to a subset of native functionality.